# Java Recursion with If statements

Tags: java, recursion

I have a Java Programming problem in which I have to use recursion with If statements in order to get this program to work. I can't use loops unfortunately which only makes this harder.

Use RECURSION to write this function.
* Asks user for a number between low and high (inclusive), reads it. 
* Keeps reading until user enters a number within range (inclusive). USE RECURSION

```
 public static int readWithinRange(Scanner in, PrintStream out, int low, int high)
 {
    // notice I'm passing the Scanner and the PrintStream; do NOT read from 
    // System.in or write to System.out

    out.println("Please enter a number.");
    int number1=in.nextInt();       
    if (number1 <= low) {
        return low;
    } else if (number1 >= high) {
        return high;
    } else if (number1 >= low && number1 <= high){
        return number1;
    } 
    return number1;
    /*return low;*/ 
 }
```

Here is the code to execute this method:

```
public void testReadWithinRange()
{
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream( " 10 20".getBytes() );
    PrintStream out=new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

    Scanner in_s=new Scanner(in);
    int ans=Assignment4.readWithinRange(in_s,out,15,25);
    Assert.assertEquals(20, ans);

    in_s=new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream( "10 20".getBytes() ));
    ans=Assignment4.readWithinRange(in_s,out,10,20);
    Assert.assertEquals(10, ans);
    in_s=new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream( "10 20 21".getBytes() ));
    Assert.assertEquals(21, Assignment4.readWithinRange(in_s,out,21,30));        
}

@Grade(points=25)
@Test
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and points will be rewarded! Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have to use recursion, why don't you use it?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: I'm new to Java and I'm not quite sure what to do in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Recursion is (roughly speaking) when a method calls itself under certain conditions.  So, under what conditions do you think `readWithinRange` might call itself?

Comment: If the number falls within a given range would be the condition in which readWithinRange  would call itself

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to call itself if the number _wasn't_ in the given range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'm suspecting you're not quite sure what recursion is. Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) for a summary.

In general the form of a recursive method will be something like:

```
func(value)
    if value is base case
        return result
    else
        combine result with func(simpler value)
```

In your case this would translate to something like:

```
int readWithinRange(int low, int high) {
    int guess = in.nextInt();
    if (guess >= low && guess <= high)
        return guess;
    else
        return readWithinRange(low, high);
}
```

Let me note that your confusion might also be a result of this being a *terrible* problem to teach recursion. It is naturally iterative and a recursive solution is not a good reflection of the problem. In particular, your problem does not require results to be combined as the recursive calls complete which makes the use of recursion completely pointless.

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate the article!